# JAXB maven plugin bindings does not generate classes with interface

Tags: java, maven, inheritance, interface, jaxb

I'm trying to generate the java files from XSD with use of jaxb2-maven-plugin. This works without any issues and I can see generated classes in target directory.

Now I decided to let all generated classes implement some interface. So I set up **bindings.xjb** file where I'm defining the interface. The issue is the plugin can not recognize correct namespace which defines inheritance.

> Unsupported binding namespace "http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/inheritance". Perhaps you meant "http://jaxb.dev.java.net/plugin/code-injector"?

I think **code-injector** is not what I'm looking for, since this allow to define custom pieces of code to add to generated file.

I'm trying to use latest maven plugin:

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.1.0</version>
```

The bindings.xjb file contains following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               xmlns:inheritance="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/inheritance"
               jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="inheritance"
               version="3.0">

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="application.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='applicationType']">
            <inheritance:implements>com.example.SomeInterface</inheritance:implements>
            <jaxb:property name="inheritance"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

And the application.xsd file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="application" type="applicationType"/>

    <xs:complexType name="applicationType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="language"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

I have found this namespace xmlns:inheritance="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/inheritance" on the internet.

Also notice plugin requires version 3.0 of bindings.xjb file.

**What is the correct definition of namespace to let plugin generate classes with interface?**

Comment: Any joy on this? Have you found a solution you can share here?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue?, please do share it, i am also facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<bindings xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb"
          xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
          extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc"
          version="3.0">
    <bindings schemaLocation="../xsd/my-schema.xsd" version="1.0">
        <globalBindings>
            <xjc:superInterface name="java.io.Serializable"/> <!-- Just example! -->
        </globalBindings>
        <bindings node="//xs:element[@name='myobject']">
            <!-- ... -->
        </bindings>
    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```